# parsing json_decode output null

Tags: php

I have tried to parse one variable from json decoded variable, i always got null, i even tried to encode to utf-8.
My code:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://ots-list.org/ajax/getServers';
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => 'server_name=Return+of+Sayians&game_type=---&client_version=---&server_country=---'
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
if ($result === FALSE) { /* Handle error */ }
//var_dump($result);
$string = mb_convert_encoding($result, "UTF-8");
$data = json_decode($string);
print $data->{'players_online'};
?>
```

Comment: Show us the content of `$data`.

Comment: NULL
"Comments must be at least 15 characters in length."

Comment: What about `$result` _before_ `mb_convert_encoding`?

Comment: $data="NULL"

$resut=string(301) "{"info":"Servers found.","serversData":[{"bgcolor":"","country":"pl","id":"13438","ip":"54.39.28.107","name":"Return of Sayians DBZ","players_online":"80","players_record":"116","uptime":"Ok<\/b>","exp_rate":"10","server_type":"PVP","client_version":"10.41"}],"status":1}"

Comment: Okay, remove everything after your "handle error" section. Replace it with `$data = json_decode($result, true);`. You can output the players_online for the first server in response with the variable `$data['serversData'][0]['players_online']`

Comment: Sadly Still NULL

Comment: Let me throw this onto my server and see if I get the same thing.

Comment: Unfortunately I've ran out of time, but from what I was seeing, that ots-list.org site is returning some json that appears valid when copied/pasted but the page itself sees it differently. I'm not really sure why.